# FileHelpers quotes issue

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

Considering this file:

```
"firstName"",lastName
fn1,ln1
fn2
fn3,ln3
fn4,ln4
```

Is there any possibility to ignore all quotes?
This is my code:

```
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public partial class Person
    {
        //[FieldQuoted]
        private string firstName;

        [FieldNullValue("default first name")]
        //[FieldQuoted]
        private string lastName;

        [FieldNotInFile]
        private string city;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }

        public string City
        {
            get { return city; }
            set { city = value; }
        }
    }   

            ExcelStorage provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(Person));
            provider.FileName = "data.csv";
            System.Data.DataTable datTable = provider.ExtractRecordsAsDT();
```

DataTable will contain only 1 row with the following values:

```
{object[2]}
    [0]: "firstName\",lastName\r\nfn1,ln1\r\nfn2\r\nfn3,ln3\r\nfn4,ln4\r\n"
    [1]: "default first name"
```

I really don't understand what is that FieldQuoted attribute, with or without it i have the same result no matter where i place quotes in the file

EDIT:
If i use

"firstName",lastName
fn1,ln1
fn2
fn3,ln3
fn4,ln4

it ignores the quotes, which is ok

but if i use

```
""firstName"",""lastName""
fn1,ln1
fn2
fn3,ln3
fn4,ln4
```

i get this result for the first row

```
[0]: "firstName\"\""
[1]: "lastName\"\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `FieldQuoted` attribute.

```
[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
```

You might need to experiment with the settings, [described here](http://www.filehelpers.com/attributes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your input data is invalid. At least, regarding the quotes. Fields in CSV can contain embedded quotes only when they are doubled (`""`) and within quotes, *and* they can contain embedded line breaks as well.

And that's exactly what you are seeing here. The two quotes following `firstName` are en embedded quote and since you never close the quoted field with another quote the whole file is parsed as if it were a single field.

Comment: Can i somehow ignore all quotes in the file?